# Laravel4: WhereHas Eloquent Issue (nested). callback function error

Tags: orm, laravel-4, eloquent

I tried doing a search function where the only field would be an `<input type='text' />` it'll be stripped into an `array()` then passed to a whereLoop.

```
static function generateSearch($fields, $queryString)
            {
                    return function($query) use($queryString, $fields)
                            {
                                    foreach($fields as $field) {
                                            $query = $query->orWhere($field, 'like', $queryString);
                                    }

                                    $query = $query->whereHas('category', function($_query) use ($queryString)
                                    {
                                            $_query->where('name','like',$queryString);
                                    });

                            };



            }

            public static function search($query)
            {

                    $searchBits = explode(' ', $query);                    

                    $query  = Lead::with(array('user', 'category'));
                    $ctr    = 0;

                    if(Category::whereIn('name', $searchBits)->count() != 0) {

                            $query = $query->whereHas('category', function($query) use ($searchBits)
                            {
                                    $ctr = 0;
                                    foreach($searchBits as $bit) {
                                            $bit            = "%".$bit."%";
                                            $callback       = "orWhere";
                                            $queryFunc = Lead::generateSearch(array('name'), $bit);

                                            if($ctr == 0) {
                                                    $callback = "where";
                                            }

                                            $query = $query->$callback($queryFunc);
                                    }
                            });

                    }else {

                            foreach($searchBits as $bit) {

                                    $bit            = "%".$bit."%";
                                    $callback       = "orWhere";
                                    $queryFunction = Lead::generateSearch(array('name', 'website', 'name', 'email'), $bit);

                                    if($ctr == 0) {
                                            $callback = "where";
                                    }
                                    $query = $query->$callback($queryFunction);

                                    $ctr++;
                            }

                    }
                    $query = $query->orderBy('id','desc');

                    return $query;
            }
```

**Category only has ONE row as of the moment: its - "hot"**

- if i type in any keyword, it'll directly go to `generateSearch()`
- but if i type in "hot", it'll send an error
- Call to undefined method
  **`Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::category()`**

does anybody know what's up?

Answer (score 0):

found the error. after looking deep within the callstack. i should not have added the

```
                $query = $query->whereHas('category', function($_query) use ($queryString) 
                {
                    $_query->where('name','like',$queryString);
                });
```

inside the generateSearch() or i should create another function for it. its being called by category callback as well.